Maintain binding when moving item from one array to another?
I have an app where a user can create events for cities. The user is able to select a date and time for each event.
On the city's page, the user is able to see all of their events and is also able to set the date and time of each event. The city's page is divided into two sections: unorganized events and organized events. Unorganized events are simply events without a date set.
So when the user navigates to the city page, my API returns two arrays: an array of unorganized events and an array of organized events.
When the user sets the date of an unorganized event, it moves the event to the organized events array.
Additionally, on the city page, the user is able to create a new event which automatically gets added to the unorganized events array.
However, I'm running into a crash which happens when:

User creates a new event
User taps on that new event
Sets the date (which adds it to the organized events array)
Sets the time (here it crashes)

The error is:

Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

I believe it may have to do with the fact that the Binding isn't maintained and it can't find the event once it's been moved from the unorganized events array to the organized events array.
Here is my code. I've left out some of the unimportant bits.
MyApp class which acts as the single source of truth:
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    @StateObject var cityManager = CityManager(cityService: CityService())

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                MainView()
                    .environmentObject(cityManager)
            }
        }
    }
}

The HomeView where I show a list of cities:
struct HomeView: View {

  @StateObject private var vm = HomeViewModel(homeService: HomeService())

  @Binding var tabSelection: Int

  @EnvironmentObject var cityManager: CityManager

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
          ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 32) {
              ForEach($cityManager.cities, id: \.id) { $city in
                CityItem(city: $city, axes: .horizontal)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
      vm.fetchHome()
    }
    .onChange(of: vm.cities?.count) {
      cityManager.cities = vm.cities ?? []
    }
    .environmentObject(cityManager)
  }
}

CityItem:
struct StadiumItem: View {
    @Binding var city: City
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: CityPageView(city: $city)) {
            VStack {
                Text(city.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

CityPageView, which is the main page that shows all of the events taking place in the city:
struct CityPageView: View {
  @Binding var city: City

  @EnvironmentObject var cityManager: CityManager
  @StateObject var cityPageViewModel = CityPageViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ZStack(alignment: .top) {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
          ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
              // List of unorganized events
              UnorganizedEventsView(city: $city)

              // List of organized events
              OrganizedEventsView(days: $city.organizedEvents)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .environmentObject(cityManager)
    .environmentObject(cityPageViewModel)
  }
}

struct UnorganizedEventsView: View {
    @Binding var city: City
    
    var body: some View {
        let unorganizedEvents = $city.unorganizedEvents
        if (!unorganizedEvents.isEmpty) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Unorganized")
                
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(unorganizedEvents, id: \.id) { $event in
                        EventView(
                            event: $event,
                            isLast: event == unorganizedEvents.wrappedValue.last
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            .id("Unorganized")
        }
    }
}

struct OrganizedEventsView: View {
    @Binding var days: [Day]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($days, id: \.id) { $day in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(day.date.toDayDate() ?? "")
                
                LazyVStack {
                    ListEventsView(events: $day.events)
                }
            }
            .id(day.date)
        }
    }
}

Here is my City model class:
struct City: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var events: [Event]? {
        didSet {
            self.unorganizedEvents = self.getUnorganizedEvents()
            self.organizedEvents = self.getOrganizedEvents()
        }
    }
    var unorganizedEvents: [Event] = []
    var organizedEvents: [Day] = []
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case events = "events"
    }
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, events: [Event] = [], unorganizedEvents: [Event] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.events = events
        self.unorganizedEvents = unorganizedEvents
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.events = try container.decodeIfPresent([Event].self, forKey: .events) ?? []
        self.unorganizedEvents = self.getUnorganizedEvents()
        self.organizedEvents = self.getOrganizedEvents()
    }
    
    func getUnorganizedEvents() -> [Event] {
        return events?.filter({ $0.date == nil }) ?? []
    }
    
    func getOrganizedEvents() -> [Day] {
        guard let events = events else {
            return []
        }
        
        var eventsByDay: [String: [Event]] = [:] // Dictionary to store events grouped by date
                
        // Group events by date
        for event in events {
            if let date = event.date {
                if var eventsOnDate = eventsByDay[date] {
                    eventsOnDate.append(event)
                    eventsByDay[date] = eventsOnDate
                } else {
                    eventsByDay[date] = [event]
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Create Day instances for each group of events
        var days: [Day] = []
        for (date, events) in eventsByDay {
            let sortedEvents = events.sorted { ($0.timeStart ?? "24:59:59") < ($1.timeStart ?? "24:59:59") }
            let day = Day(date: date, events: sortedEvents)
            days.append(day)
        }
        
        days.sort { $0.date < $1.date }
        
        return days
    }
}

What am I doing wrong that would cause this crash?

Edit
Based on comments, I've decided to rely on just 1 array. However, I'm struggling on how to filter the events while keeping the filtered array updated when the original city.events gets updated.
struct CityListView: View {
    @Binding var city: City
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {

                // Here, I want to filter by events where date = nil
                ForEach($city.events, id: \.id) { $event in
                    EventView(
                        event: $event
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is my City model:
struct City: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var events: [Event] = []
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case events = "events"
    }
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, events: [Event] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.events = events
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.events = try container.decodeIfPresent([Event].self, forKey: .events) ?? []
    }
}


There is a lot of code to sift through.
On which line of the code does the error occurs?
To avoid such array indexing problems,
I suggest instead of transferring Event types to Day types in two separate arrays,
try using one single array of the same type. Each element having a flag or something similar, that can be
unorganized or organized. Then use a simple .filter(...) to get the appropriate events. With just one array things don't get out of sync.

@StateObject isn’t for view models that’s what the View structs are for. onChange is for external actions like logging not for syncing states, use computed bindings for that.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I've decided to try what you suggested, but I'm confused as to how to keep the filtered array updated. I've added updated code to my question under the "Edit", if you could please help.

Try this approach using a filter in the ForEach loop.
Since you have the added requirement of a binding for
EventView, the code is slightly more involved than just a straight filter.
Here is the test code that displays only the events with date == nil as you require.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var city = City(id: 1, name: "Tokyo", events: [Event(name: "manga", date: Date()), Event(name: "event0", date: nil), Event(name: "event1", date: nil),Event(name: "event2", date: nil)])
    
    var body: some View {
        CityListView(city: $city)
    }
}

struct EventView: View {
    @Binding var event: Event
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(event.name)
            TextField("", text: $event.name).border(.red)
        }
    }
}

struct CityListView: View {
    @Binding var city: City
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                // Here, I want to filter by events where date = nil
                ForEach(city.filteredEvents()) { event in  // <--- EDIT-1 
                // ForEach(city.events.filter{ $0.date == nil }) { event in
                    if let index = city.events.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == event.id}) {
                        EventView(event: $city.events[index])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct City: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var events: [Event] = []

    func filteredEvents() -> [Event] {  
        events.filter{ $0.date == nil }  // <--- EDIT-1 
    }
}

struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var date: Date?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, date
    }
}

EDIT-1:
moving the filtering inside the City struct.

Is it possible to put the filter as a variable in the City model? That way I can use it elsewhere in the app.

Updated my answer, moving the filtering inside the City struct. See EDIT-1
